# Labeling angles in a triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I've tried looking at past answers to this question but it won't seem to solve my problem.

I want to label the angles ABD and DBC in this triangle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb,tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \tkzInit[xmin=-0.5,xmax=6.7,ymin=-0.7,ymax=3.5]
    \tkzClip[space=0.25]

    \coordinate (A) at (0,0); \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
    \coordinate (B) at (2.25,3.320718914); \tkzLabelPoints[above](B)
    \coordinate (C) at (6,0); \tkzLabelPoints[right](C)
    \coordinate (E) at (3,0); \tkzLabelPoints[below](E)
    \draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
    \draw (B)--(E);

    \tkzDefLine[bisector](A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{a}
    \tkzInterLL(A,C)(B,a) \tkzGetPoint{D} \tkzLabelPoints[below](D)
    \draw (B)--(D);

    \tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{12}
    \tkzLabelPoints[left](12)
    \tkzDefMidPoint(B,C) \tkzGetPoint{15}
    \tkzLabelPoints[right=0.1cm](15)
    \tkzDefMidPoint(A,C) \tkzGetPoint{18}
    \tkzLabelPoints[below=0.4cm](18)

    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,E)
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](C,E)

    \tkzLabelSegment(A,B)
    \tkzLabelSegment(B,C)
    \tkzLabelSegment(C,A)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `angles` library for that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb,tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \tkzInit[xmin=-0.5,xmax=6.7,ymin=-0.7,ymax=3.5]
    \tkzClip[space=0.25]

    \coordinate (A) at (0,0); \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
    \coordinate (B) at (2.25,3.320718914); \tkzLabelPoints[above](B)
    \coordinate (C) at (6,0); \tkzLabelPoints[right](C)
    \coordinate (E) at (3,0); \tkzLabelPoints[below](E)
    \draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
    \draw (B)--(E);

    \tkzDefLine[bisector](A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{a}
    \tkzInterLL(A,C)(B,a) \tkzGetPoint{D} \tkzLabelPoints[below](D)
    \draw (B)--(D);

    \tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{12}
    \tkzLabelPoints[left](12)
    \tkzDefMidPoint(B,C) \tkzGetPoint{15}
    \tkzLabelPoints[right=0.1cm](15)
    \tkzDefMidPoint(A,C) \tkzGetPoint{18}
    \tkzLabelPoints[below=0.4cm](18)

    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,E)
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](C,E)

%    \tkzLabelSegment(A,B)
%    \tkzLabelSegment(B,C)
%    \tkzLabelSegment(C,A)
    \draw pic[draw=blue, angle radius=5mm] {angle = A--B--D};
    \draw pic[draw=red, angle radius=7mm] {angle = D--B--C};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's great. I was wondering if there was a way to make a dash going through the angles similar to the one going through the AE and AC segments.

Comment: @SamFisher     I don't know a fast way know. You can make a follow-up question. By the way, `tkz-euclide` has `\tkzMarkAngle` which is equivalent to `angle` pic. And for dashes, you can find the angle midpoint and draw a little segment on it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\tkzFindAngle`, `tkzGetAngle`, `tkzMarkAngle` and `tkzLabelAngle`.

By the way, doing

```
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{12}
\tkzLabelPoints[left](12)
```

And doing

```
\tkzLabelSegment[left](A,B){12}
```

is the same (in this case at least). But as you can see the command is much shorter. I would use that if I was you. I had corrected it from your code because `\tkzLabelSegment(A,B)` was missing the name between curly brackets.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \tkzInit[xmin=-0.5,xmax=6.7,ymin=-0.7,ymax=3.5]
    \tkzClip[space=0.25]

    \coordinate (A) at (0,0); \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
    \coordinate (B) at (2.25,3.320718914); \tkzLabelPoints[above](B)
    \coordinate (C) at (6,0); \tkzLabelPoints[right](C)
    \coordinate (E) at (3,0); \tkzLabelPoints[below](E)
    \draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
    \draw (B)--(E);

    \tkzDefLine[bisector](A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{a}
    \tkzInterLL(A,C)(B,a) \tkzGetPoint{D} \tkzLabelPoints[below](D)
    \draw (B)--(D);

    \tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{12}
    \tkzLabelPoints[left](12)
    \tkzDefMidPoint(B,C) \tkzGetPoint{15}
    \tkzLabelPoints[right=0.1cm](15)
    \tkzDefMidPoint(A,C) \tkzGetPoint{18}
    \tkzLabelPoints[below=0.4cm](18)

    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,E)
    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](C,E)

    \tkzFindAngle(A,B,D) 
    \tkzFindAngle(D,B,C)
    \tkzGetAngle{angleABD}; \FPround\angleABD\angleABD{0}
    \tkzGetAngle{angleDBC}; \FPround\angleDBC\angleDBC{0}

    \tkzMarkAngle[draw=black,opacity=.5,fill=green!10](A,B,D)
    \tkzMarkAngle[draw=black,opacity=.5,fill=red!10](D,B,C)
    \tkzLabelAngle[dist=1.2](A,B,D){\tiny $\angleABD^\circ$}
    \tkzLabelAngle[dist=1.2](D,B,C){\tiny $\angleDBC^\circ$}

    %\tkzLabelSegment[left](A,B){AB}
    %\tkzLabelSegment[right](B,C){BC}
    %\tkzLabelSegment[below](C,A){CA}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```